# Python Schematics model conversion error rouge field

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pip, pycharm

Please help me on this, I have a model like this which i wanted to import,

```
cricket:
 players:
  1 : Mike
  2 : Mark
  3 : Miller
 scores:
  12: 222
  13: 255
  15: 555
```

When using `DictType(ModelType(CricModel), default=None, deserialize_from=('cricket', 'params'))` it's throwing error.

Am i doing it correctly

Answer (score 0):

Need to use ModelType(ModelName) rather thans DictType